# PHP - Calling a Class Method

Tags: php, methods

I've been handed a PHP class, and I'm not interested in fully restructuring it.  (it works!)

But I'd like to add a slight modification inside a few methods.

Here is one of the many methods inside the class:

```
<?php
class SomeFunClass {

    public function getAccountInfo()
    {
        $request  = $this->prepareRequest('get_account_info');
        $response = $this->execute($request);
        return $response;
    }

}
?>
```

The return **$response** is a string value.
I've come to a point that I need to return the **$request** string, which happens to be a `json` string.

The **prepareRequest()** method always returns a `json` string, which is then passed to the **exec()** method, which simply sends the data via cURL to a domain.

I'd like to extract the **$request** string (when I call the **getAccountInfo()** method), for later review.

Here's what I'm doing now:

```
<?php

   $api = new SomeFunClass();
   $curlresponse = $api->getAccountInfo();

?>
```

Obviously, the example immediately above only gives me back what the cURL response would be.
Would be nice to call a method that lets me see what the **$request** looks like.
I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: You won't be able to get at the `$request` variable unless you modify the source code of `SomeFunClass::getAccountInfo`. There's no magic way to reach into the method and get a variable out. Well, unless you're talking about a live debugger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
<?php
class SomeFunClass {

    public $request;
    public $response;

    public function getAccountInfo()
    {
        $this->request  = $this->prepareRequest('get_account_info');
        $this->response = $this->execute($this->request);
        return $this->response;
    }

}
?>
```

Now, you can do something like this:

```
<?php

   $api = new SomeFunClass();
   $curlresponse = $api->getAccountInfo();
   $request = $api->request;
?>
```

Ideally, you can do implement your class like this to take actual advantage of OOP (so that these instance variables `request` and `response` are auto-set for all your methods):

```
<?php
class SomeFunClass {

    public $request;
    public $response;

    public function getAccountInfo()
    {
        $this->prepareRequest('get_account_info');
        return $this->execute();
    }


    public function anotherMethod()
    {
        $this->prepareRequest('another_method', 'some', 'args');
        return $this->execute();
    }

    public function prepareRequest()
    {
        $args = func_get_args();      // contains your arguments
        $method = array_shift($args); // contains your method name
        ...
        ...
        $this->request  = $return // value returned by this method
    }


    public function execute()
    {
        $request = $this->request;
        ...
        ...
        $this->response = $return // value returned by this method
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Why would you want to save unnecessary information to the object?

Comment: Cause it makes less modifications than modifying the return of those methods, which implies to modify scripts that use it too.

Comment: @qwertynl: added example code on why someone would prefer my kind of approach :)

Answer (score 2):

Just return an array with the request **and** the response:

```
<?php
class SomeFunClass {

    public function getAccountInfo()
    {
        $request  = $this->prepareRequest('get_account_info');
        $response = $this->execute($request);
        return array('request' => $request, 'response' => $response);
    }

}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can modify those methods to store the last request into an attribute of the current class :

```
<?php

class SomeFunClass {

    $last_request;

    ...

    public function getAccountInfo()
    {
        $request  = $this->prepareRequest('get_account_info');
        $last_request = request;
        $response = $this->execute($request);
        return $response;
    }

    public function getLastRequest()
    {
        return $this -> last_request;
    }
}

?>
```

Or, better, if `prepareRequest` is a method of yours, then just modify this one to store the last request.

Answer (score 0):

You could also do this:

```
<?php

class SomeFunClass {

    public function reviewRequest($request)
    {
        return $this->prepareRequest($request);
    }

}
```

And then:

```
<?php

   $api = new SomeFunClass();
   $request = $api->reviewRequest('get_account_info');
```